# How to apply StaticResource using Textbox.Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, staticresource

I have a textbox using **AddItemsTextBoxStyle** (defined in resource dictionary), as below:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtItems" Style="{StaticResource AddItemsTextBoxStyle}" />
```

However, if I want to apply DataTrigger to my textbox, then I can't use the self-closing tags format. Instead, I need to reformat my textbox to something like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtItems">
   <TextBox.Style>
       <Style>
           <Style.Triggers>

                ...

           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Sorry if this sounds silly. But how can I apply "static resource" for my textbox by using "TextBox.Style" tag?

Comment: Did ou try adding the triggers to your AddItemsTextBoxStyle style?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot for some reason, I want to add the triggers outside the AddItemsTextBoxStyle style, hmm.

Comment: ?? You want to add it outside the style? What do you mean? Take your <Style> element, give it a x:Name="AddItemsTextBoxStyle" and a TargetType="TextBox".

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Style.BasedOn` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx) to combine your pre defined `Style` and your `Trigger` like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtItems">
   <TextBox.Style>
       <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource AddItemsTextBoxStyle}">
           <Style.Triggers>

                ...

           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Tried but seems like textbox don't have BasedOn property.

Comment: The `BasedOn` property is on the `Style` class.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's my bad... I added it to the wrong line.